# KDB how to use $[] in query

Tags: kdb

If I have a table

```
t: flip `a`b`c!(til 10;10?(1b,0b);10?(1b,0b))
```

why can I do this

```
update x:?[b;1;?[c;3;0]] from t
```

but not

```
update x:$[b;1;c;3;0] from t
```

[which returns a rank error] 
while this

```
b:0b
c:1b
$[b;1;c;3;0]
```

works fine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$` is the standard [conditional](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/control/#cond) operator that only works with atomic values. `?` is [vector conditional](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/lists/#vector-conditional) operator that works with both atomic and vector conditions.

The columns in a table are vectors and as a result using `$` results in an error whereas `?` does not. To use `$` with a table you need to pass the values to it individually, an example of this might be:

```
update x:{$[x;1;y;3;0]}'[b;c] from t
```